# Problem with loading relations in Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine ORM for PHP and I have a question about loading relations. A model seems to load a different set of relations based on how it was loaded, does anyone know a way around this?

That might be a bit confusing. Here's an example. Say we have model A and model B, with a many to many relationship - A has one or more Bs. In my data set I have one A record, "A1", which is related to two B records, "B1" & "B2".

There's two ways I need to load an A record, but in both scenarios I want to be able to get all related B records using `$myModelA->B`.

The first scenario is by loading "A1" directly. So I'd go `$myModelA = A_Table->find("A1")`, simple. Then when I go `$myModelA->B`, I will be able to see both "B1" & "B2". This is expected.

The second scenario causes the problems. I want to find all A records that are related to "B2". So I create a Doctrine_Query and do a join between A and B and specify that I want A records that are related to "B2". Now I want to go through my list of A records, one of which is "A1". So since I have the "A1" model in `$myModelA`, same as in the first scenario, I expect that when I go `$myModelA->B` I can see both "B1" & "B2".

But this isn't the case. I only see "B2". I presume this is because the query I used to retrieve "A1" in the first place required only "B2" related records, so then when I follow the relation back the other way that condition is somehow still in place and so I can only get "B2".

Question is…how do to force the model in scenario two to ignore the previous query and load all related records to that model?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some documented code comparable to the form of: [Relationships](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#relationships)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can call `refresh()` on A. Make sure you call it with `true` as argument, so that your relation is refreshed.

```
$A1->refresh(true);
```